# Fail2ban does not perform regex on odoo log

Tags: ubuntu, python, fail2ban, odoo

I have installed fail2ban with odoo 13.

Below are my configuration and sample output, but I cant seem to figure out why it does not filter.

**user@tempdev:/etc/fail2ban# fail2ban-regex -v /var/log/odoo/odoo.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/odoo-login.conf**

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : odoo-login, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /var/log/odoo/odoo.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [0] ^\d+ INFO \S+ \S+ Login failed for db:\S+ login:\S+ from <HOST>
`-
```

**user@tempdev:/etc/fail2ban# cat /var/log/odoo/odoo.log | grep 'Login failed'**

```
2020-12-11 12:54:06,442 1620 INFO TestSRV odoo.addons.base.models.res_users: Login failed for db:TestSRV login:asfd from 1.2.23.3 
2020-12-11 13:11:20,945 1620 INFO TestSRV odoo.addons.base.models.res_users: Login failed for db:TestSRV login:asfd from 1.2.23.3 
2020-12-11 13:12:07,928 1620 INFO TestSRV odoo.addons.base.models.res_users: Login failed for db:TestSRV login:asdf from 1.2.23.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fail2ban surely cuts the part of string matched datepattern out, but a space still remains, so you have to add `\s*` after the anchor before `\d+`:

```
-failregex = ^\d+ INFO \S+ \S+ Login failed for db:\S+ login:\S+ from <HOST>
+failregex = ^\s*\d+ INFO \S+ \S+ Login failed for db:\S+ login:\S+ from <HOST>
```